# SonarQube AD group members are not populated

Tags: ldap, sonarqube5.3

I am testing the new LDAP Plugin 1.5.1 with SonarQube 5.3 Community version on my local PC.

According to the instructions here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Microsoft+Active+Directory. I added the following lines in sonar.properties. I kept admin/admin for testing now.

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.localUsers=admin
```

I've created these domain groups in AD, with some members. e.g. my id huj is in AP-SonarQube-Admin-Dev group.

I then created the same set of domain groups inside SonarQube. Add them into the Global Permission, set the Project Permission, etc.

However, after login, these groups are all empty as shown below. In my login profile, the group is also empty, so I can't even see the projects. So the members of these AD groups have not been populated into the same groups in SonarQube.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD group names are by default returned in lower case, see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin
and the property

```
ldap.windows.group.downcase
```

You might try setting

```
sonar.log.level=DEBUG
```

and sonar.log will most likely provide you with the proper group names to use, like "group@domain".

Hope this helps.